# Array manipulation: Index Out of Bounds

Tags: arrays, ms-access, vba

I am trying to compare one array of strings with another to see if all the elements of the first array are present in the second. I am doing this with the following function:

```
    Dim tempArray As Object
    Set tempArray = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    For j = 0 To maxNumberOfParts - 1
        tempArray.Add (kitPartsArray(i, j))
    Next

    j = 0

    While UBound(partIDs) <= tempArray.Count
        Debug.Print (UBound(partIDs) & " " & tempArray.Count & " " & LBound(partIDs))
        If partIDs(j) = tempArray(j) Then
            j = j + 1
        Else
            tempArray.Remove (tempArray(j))
        End If
    Wend
    Debug.Print tempArray(1)
    j = 0
    Exists = True
    For Each part In partIDs
        Debug.Print tempArray(j)
        If part <> tempArray(j) Then
            Exists = False
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next

    If Exists Then
        DoesntExist = False
        existingKits.Add (i)
    Else
        DoesntExist = True
    End If
```

The idea is that it will start with the first string in each array and compare them. If they are the same, it will move to the next string in each array, but if they are different, it will remove the string from the temp array. Then the process will happen again with the string that has filled in for the deleted string. This continues until the two arrays are the same size. Then they are compared and if they are the same, then all the elements of the first array must be in the temp array. However, I am getting an out of bounds error on the line:

```
If part <> tempArray(j) Then
```

(It actually occurs on the Debug.Print tempArray(1) and Debug.Print tempArray(j) but when those are removed it is on the If statement)

You can see it prints out tempArray.Count and on the last pass through that While...Wend loop, it prints this as being 2. UBound(partIDs) is also 2. I can't understand why tempArray is shrinking in that interim or if it isn't then why it is not able to access those elements.

UPDATE:
When the .Count property is at 2, Debug.Print tempArray(j) prints one value before throwing an error. When .Count is 3, it prints two values, and when at 4, it prints three values.

Comment: j is 1 and .Count is 2.

Comment: Im pretty sure you cant use debug.print with Array iteration references. I cant remember but i am pretty sure this gave me a massive headache before

Comment: I get the same error in the If statement below when I remove it so I don't think that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It is possible for partIDs to be a larger array than tempArray and while I had precautions in place against it being the opposite way, I hadn't safeguarded against this occurrence. I just had to add in this If statement to make it work:

```
    j = 0
    Exists = True
    For Each part In partIDs
        If UBound(partIDs) < tempArray.Count Then
            Debug.Print tempArray(j) & " New"
            If part <> tempArray(j) Then
                Exists = False
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Else
            Exists = False
        End If
    Next
```